# Syncing music with Ubuntu One

Tags: ubuntu-one

If I want to make use of Ubuntu One's mobile streaming service, how do I add (my own) music to Ubuntu One?

I mean, if I purchase music through the music store, the music automatically get synced. But how (or rather where) do I add my own collection for synchronization?

Answer (score 11):

The easiest way to add all your own music is just to mark the folder it's in as being synced with Ubuntu One.

See [Ubuntu One : Help : FAQs - How do I move my existing music to Ubuntu One?](https://one.ubuntu.com/help/faq/how-do-i-move-my-existing-music-to-ubuntu-one/) for details.

Basically, just right-click on your Music folder (or wherever your music is stored) and pick **Ubuntu One > Synchronize this folder** from the context menu. This will copy your music into your personal cloud, and then it's all available for streaming.